# d3 Scale rect width based on window size

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and is testing some D3 programs. I need to scale the rectangle's width when window size increases or descreases. As of now I do not know what goes in the function `widthScale`.

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append("svg");

var _data = ["apple", "banana", "carrots", "grapes"];

var rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(_data).enter();

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(_data)
  .rangePoints([10, 200]);

var widthScale = d3.scale.linear() // I do not know what to do here so that I can get the rect to increase the width when window scales
  .domain([0])
  .range([0]);

rects.append('rect')
  .attr({
    "x": function(d) {
      return xScale(d);
    },
    "y": 15,
    "width": 50, // the width needs to scale when the window size increases or decreases and leave a little space in between each.
    //"width" : widthScale(something), //This is what i want
    "height": 15
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not just set a viewBox on the root svg element?

Comment: @RobertLongson despite your suggestion being, by far, the most obvious and easy solution, I believe it's a good exercise for the OP doing this the way he/she wants. I'm saying this because, if he/she understands how to change the rect attributes on windows resize, it will be a good learning towards writing a **real** responsive chart code, in which he can change colours, elements, texts etc on resize.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado That's why I posted a comment to the OP. They might not realise there's a really easy way to do this, or they might realise it and have discarded it for some reason. If only the OP had posted more about their research...

Comment: Indeed, you're right, this may be a simple *XY problem*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to create a responsive SVG like this, but I'll try to keep most of your code here.

My approach consists in using `rabgeBands` in the xScale, instead of `rangePoints`:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(_data)
    .rangeBands([10, width - 10]);
```

So, every time `width` changes (more on that below), we'll have a new `scale.rangeBand()`, which we simply use in for the width of the rectangles:

```
rects.attr({
    "x": function(d) {
        return xScale(d);
    },
    "y": 15,
    "width": xScale.rangeBand() * 0.95,
    "height": 20
});
```

The magic number 0.95 (95%) here is just a padding.

After those changes, we dump everything inside a `draw` function, which we call when the window is resized:

```
d3.select(window).on("resize", draw);
```

Inside `draw`, we get the new window width...

```
width = window.innerWidth;
```

... and use that value to change the scale domain and the SVG width.

Here is a demo:

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;

var colors = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("width", width);

var _data = ["apple", "banana", "carrots", "grapes"];

var rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(_data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors(i);
  });

draw();

d3.select(window).on("resize", draw);

function draw() {

  width = window.innerWidth;

  svg.attr("width", width)

  var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(_data)
    .rangeBands([10, width - 10]);

  rects.attr({
    "x": function(d) {
      return xScale(d);
    },
    "y": 15,
    "width": xScale.rangeBand() * 0.95,
    "height": 20
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the same code in a fiddle, which is easier to resize: https://jsfiddle.net/oav639xj/

Comment: I have a better understanding on how to resize and adjust width based on the example you provided. Could you take a look at the code I updated [link](https://jsfiddle.net/oav639xj/2/). The code is similar, I added another data to know how multiple elements can be redrawn at once. It does not seem to work. Can you just change the code on there so that I can take a look at it please?

Comment: Do you want this? https://jsfiddle.net/tz6z7tyv/ You just forgot to change the y attribute. besides that, you're reselecting rectangles.